# Is f(x)=0 considered continous?

Tags: calculus, continuity

I'm aware that constant functions are considered continuous, but would $f(x)=0$ be considered a continuous function everywhere? Does $0$ count as a constant?

Comment: Yes, 0 is a constant.

Comment: Ok, just making sure, thank you.

Comment: f(x)=0 is a constant function. A constant function is continuous everywhere regardless of the constant value.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the definition of continuous is:

$$lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c)$$

Since the limit is just 0 for all x value, so the whole function is continuous

Answer (score 9):

Indeed it is continuous. Using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity, we find that $\forall c\in \mathbb R$ and $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\forall x\in\mathbb R$

$$|x-c| <\delta \implies |f(x) - f(c)| = 0 < \epsilon$$

Clearly, $\delta$ can be anything, so the continuity holds.

Answer (score 6):

f(x)=0 is a continuous function because it is an unbroken line, without holes or jumps. All numbers are constants, so yes, 0 would be a constant.

Comment: A function can be discontinuous without having a hole or a jump. Let $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I know, I just put two possible ways. Asymptotes are another possible way

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is continuous and 0 is a constant